# System and compressed memory consuming my disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, task-manager, tasks

Whenever i start my PC, this task consumes 100% of my disk as shown in the picture below.

[image: System and compressed memory]

Could anyone help me avoid this?

**My PC Specifications:**

- Disk: 500GB
- RAM: 20GB
- Processor: Core(TM) i5

Comment: Do you really have 20 GB RAM? Because it's full. If that happens right after booting, something is very wrong.

Comment: What ar you doing that has 20GB of RAM 92% used? If you close some of those programs then the system will probably be less memory starved and page less out to disk, relieving your problem.

Comment: when does it happen? directly after boot or later after some time?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% of your disk (MS has bad terminology for disk and CPU usage) -- they are calling 100% is 100% of your disk's "speed" or bandwidth.  Of course, how fast your disk is and how the OS would know, is questionable.

My system can do 20MB/s w/o anything noticing.  Maybe the OS is measuring
the number of outstanding I/O requests and if the # of I/O requests, waiting to be satisfied is "high", then it assumes your disk is operating at full speed and isn't keeping up.

Besides getting a SSD as davidgo mentioned above, you might try defragmenting the disk -- but more importantly, is to turn off programs that are loading at startup that you don't need.

Go get sysinternals "autoruns" and it will show you all the things that run automatically.  Look at the logon section for programs that run at login and see if you use all the programs being started.

Lots of times lots of junk gets started when the OS starts, and it bogs everything down.

Same goes for Windows Services -- turn off ones you *know* you don't need (or google for "which windows 10 services are needed at boot", and see what comes up).  If you need them, see if it makes sense to have them start ~20-30 seconds after boot ("delayed start").

Basically it's telling you that your disk is 100% busy (not 100% full).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is anything intrinsically wrong here.  The solution is to move your OS onto an SSD.

The mitigation would be to reduce the number of programs that run on startup.  You might also get a bit of mileage by defragging your hard drive which could make loading some files faster - but its not going to be anything like as good as replacing the OS partition with an SSD.

Explanation: Your hard drive is maxing out IO and pushing 20MB/Sec because files are small and scattered all over the place - a hard drive doing sequential IO can typically do 5 times this - but file loads are not sequential - and SSD's can typically do 100-200 times this because they don't care where on the SSD the data is stored.